# The best practice to use Spark's generated mllib model as a server

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to find out what the proper way is to use a model generated by Spark+MLlib (in this case a Collaborative Filtering Recommendation Engine) to provide predictions quickly, on demand, and as a server.

My current solution is to run an instance of Spark continuously for this purpose, but I wanted to know whether there are better solutions to this, perhaps a solution that does not require a running Spark. Perhaps there is a way to load and use a generated model by Spark without involving Spark?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a model via pmml and then take that model and use it in another application.

Comment: Very cool idea. I am however not sure if the Collaborative Filtering models can be exported as a PMML file. According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html, Collaborative Filtering is not among the options.

Answer (score 0):

Now i find the way。 First,we can save als model's product_features and user_feaures by `model.productFeatures() and Model.userFeatures()`

Then we get product features like this

```
209699159874445020 
0.0533636957407,-0.0878632888198,0.105949401855,0.129774808884,0.0953511446714,0.16420891881,0.0558457262814,0.0587058141828
```

So we can load product features and user features into two dicts in python and make a server by tornado to predict ratings using these two dicts. I will show the code for example.

```
def predict(item_id, user_id):
    ind = item_id_index[item_id]
    gf =  goods_features[ind,1:]
    ind = user_id_index[user_id]
    uf = user_features[ind,1:]
    return blas.ddot(gf,uf,len(gf),0,1,0,1)
```

As conclusion. We need to persist als model by ourselves and it isn't as difficult as we thought. Any suggestions are welcome.